# Piping in C: Child process never knows when there is no more input

Tags: c

I want to make a program that sends floats from the parent to the child process and then does some mathematical operations on them.

The input should come from stdin in the parent process and be piped to the child process. The Child process should take every value and add them up. However I can't figure out how to check if there is no more input coming from the parent process.

I tried checking if there is something in the pipe. However it simply skips the while loop if I start the program because there is nothing initially in the pipe. Can someone help me?

```
int fdp[2];
int fdc[2];
pid_t f;

f = fork();

if (f > 0) { 
double x,y;

      while( fscanf(stdin, "%lf", x) > 0 ) {
           y = x*x;
           write(fdp[1], &y, sizeof(y))
}
.....


else if (f==0) {
double y;
       while(read(fdp[1], "%lf", &y) > 0) {
         //calculate something
        }
```

I cut out the closing of unnecesary pipes and so on. But I hope the problem is clear: The child process simply skips the while loop, because there is nothing in the pipe in the beginning. But it should keep reading, until there is a wrong input ( something that cnat be converted to a double ) in the parent process.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You simply need to close the pipe in the parent and check for `EOF` from the the child `read`. The [pipe](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) manual even gives an example of that. If you need further help then please give complete code as a [mre].

Comment: Sorry @John3136
I changed the order for this post here and forgot to remove the comment

Comment: @kaylum Thank you. I just needed to look in the docs. My usage was right, but however I used the parameters of read incorrectly. I found the mistake now, thanks.